# Turning loop into arithmetics to speed up function

Tags: c, optimization, pipeline, branch-prediction

Hi I am on my way to optimize a function that is supposed to give me the "next" of something. So far what I have got is

```
  int fun(int a){
    const int k = ...;
    for(;test_value(a++) != k;);
    return a;
   }
```

This was a quick and dirty way to test that my algorithm actually worked but now afterwards I am worried that the loop makes a test for branching on every iteration (if not the compiler is very good at handling it behind the scenes?). Let us say the chance that any a fulfils the test is at most 1/5 and worst cases one in a million but that test_value is just a clock cycle or two. Is there some systematic way I can help my compiler trade all the branches with arithmetics to better utilize the CPU pipelines?

Comment: You don't think that would depend on just what `test_value` is?

Comment: It is a function that should execute in just a few cycles without any risk of branching. Probably exists as SSE instruction on modern machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "unroll" your loop a bit, something like:

```
int nomatch = 1;
while( nomatch ){
    nomatch   = (test_value(a++) != k);
    nomatch &&= (test_value(a++) != k);
    nomatch &&= (test_value(a++) != k);
    nomatch &&= (test_value(a++) != k);
    nomatch &&= (test_value(a++) != k);
}
```

This would yield fewer iterations, and short-circuiting would prevent the evaluations of `test_value` once a match has been found.

Like your original code, this assumes that a match will be found at some point.

Comment: Great idea, helped me find a solution.